# jquery trigger error message to server when a event not supported by client browser

Tags: jquery, modernizr

I want to send an error message to the server when a jquery event is not supported by the browser.
For example *blur() event will not get triggered for radio button in chrome browser*.
How can i identify this and send error message to the server?

**UPDATE**

I tried Modernizr.hasEvent on radio button for blur event.Eventhough it returns true blur event is not getting called in google chrome.Try the below jsfiddle in google chrome.

**html**

```
<input type = 'radio' id = 'r1' name = 'r1' value = 'R1'>R1</input>
<input type = 'radio' id = 'r2' name = 'r1' Value = 'R2'>R2</input>
<input type = 'text' id = 'r3'  Value = ''></input>
```

**js**

```
alert(Modernizr.hasEvent('blur',$('#r1')));
alert(Modernizr.hasEvent('blur',$('#r3')));
$('#r1').blur(function(){
  alert('blur is called')
});
$('#r3').blur(function(){
  alert('blur is called')
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nUN8k/23/

Comment: You can detect supported functionality using jQuery.support variable. You can send messages to the server using AJAX.

Comment: @JanDvorak Modernizr not working.Try http://jsfiddle.net/nUN8k/23/ on google chrome

Comment: @shiva The problem with chrome is not it doesn't fire `blur`. The problem is that it never gets focus in the first place. Try tabbing on `R1` - the `blur` then fires when you click away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with chrome is not it doesn't support `blur` on radio buttons. The problem is that the radio button never gets focused in the first place.

Try this in [your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nUN8k/23/):

Test 1:

- Click R1
- Click R2
- Click away

The event doesn't fire, but no focus (an orange border) is indicated either.

Test 2:

- Click R3
- Press Shift+tab (and dismiss the blur alert). R2 should be focused but not selected.
- Press the left key. R1 gets selected and focused.
- Click away. R1 registers a blur event.

So, the event *is* supported in Chrome - only it doesn't fire when you expect.

The workaround is to focus the radio button manually when it is clicked so that you get cross-browser *consistent* (not just valid) behavior:

```
$("input").click(function(){
    $(this).focus()
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nUN8k/24/

The test - I haven't checked if it works and I don't know if it's implemented in modernizr - would be to click a hidden input and see if it get focused. However, there could be some false positives (mistaken for Don't focus hidden elements etc.) ...